# How to move certain column data from 1st table to 2nd table. And filling other columns of 2nd table with different data in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I know about this query:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3)

SELECT column1, column2, column3,

FROM table1

WHERE condition;
```

Let's say, I have at least 5 columns in table2. I want to get data of first three columns from table1 for table 2. I can do this with the above query. But I also want to fill other 2 columns of table2 with some data that is stored in variables. Is there any way to do so?

I want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3,column4,column5)

VALUES(

SELECT column1, column2, column3,

FROM table1

WHERE condition 

, @dataForColumn4, @dataForColumn5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just include them in the `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)
    SELECT column1, column2, column3, @column4, @column5
    FROM table1
    WHERE condition;
```